# Angular Material mat-tree with checkboxes select all

Tags: angular, checkbox, tree, angular-material

I'm using [Tree with checkboxes](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gabkadkvybq?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.html), and I want to add a button to check all checkboxes, I tried different methods but no good, the best thing i was able to achieve is this:

```
  selectAllFiscal() {
    this.rootItems.forEach(node => {
      this.todoItemSelectionToggle(node);
    });
  }
```

rootItems is an array of root nodes.

I can see that nodes are selected when I iterate `checklistSelection.selected`, but the checkboxes are not selected in the browser, can anybody point the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following for your method

```
  checkAll(){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) {
      if(!this.checklistSelection.isSelected(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]))
        this.checklistSelection.toggle(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);
      this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])
    }
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpsj5x?embed=1&file=app/tree-checklist-example.html

Comment: this has a bug in it, if you already had selected a node, when you press checkAll is deselecting the already existing selection

Comment: See revision to stackblitz. You are correct, but you can leverage the `isSelected()` function of the SelectionModel. This in my opinion would be less verbose and a more readable syntax for your development team members versus using `this.select` in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer has a bug in it, if you press select all and you already had selected a checkbox from the tree it s doing only toggle, not select/deselect-all. 
This is my solution:

In Html use something simillar to this:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isAllSelected" (change)="selectAll()">Select all</mat-checkbox>
```

And in your component:

```
selectAll(): void {
    this.select = !this.select;
    this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach((r, index) => {
      this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[index]);
      this.select
        ? this.checklistSelection.select(this.treeControl.dataNodes[index])
        : this.checklistSelection.deselect(this.treeControl.dataNodes[index]);
    });
    this.isAllSelected = true;
  }
```

Comment: You should use `this.checklistSelection.isSelected()` to check the current state of the checkbox, it is what the function is there for. See revision above to the original answer.

Comment: @Marshal you need to keep track of your flag for the toggle effect.